# Comparing two arrays to get the difference and (possibly) returning a single array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, diff

I have a MYSQL table to record status log updates for a web app.

There are several fields that will be populated but the thing is not all fields will be updated at one time.

What I am planning on is pulling the last log entry (if one exists), and comparing this to the new data coming in. If anything in the new value is blank, it would inherit the value from the previous values set.

I should mention that this is to allow viewing of the changes and tracking the logs as they are updated.

So I am wondering what the best way to approach this is. Right now my plan is pull my previous values and loop through comparing this to the `$submittedData` array (using if statements). When `$submittedData` has a value differing from the previous data, it will take the value from `$submittedData`. However if a value in `$submittedData` is empty, it will retain the value from the previous set.

I am aware of the 4 different array_diff functions in php, but not sure if I should use them, if this would help me, or if I am over thinking this. What would be idea is writing a function I could just pass the two array's to and have it return an array of the same structure (associative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) solves all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *add* the arrays (it also should faster than `array_merge()`). So basically, if you have `$previousData`and `$submittedData` you can simply do:

```
$finalData = $submittedData + $previousData; //It is *not* commutative
```

All values from `$previousData` that are not present in the first array will be merged into `$finalData` together with all `$submittedData` values.